For a 2D anisotropic medium, how can it be shown that $k_a = \sqrt{k_1 k_2}$ when $\theta = 45^{\circ}$ and $W/L=1$?
where $k_1$ and $k_2$ are the principal conductivities of the medium and $k_1 \ne k_2$; $\theta$ is the angle between the $k_1$ axis and the $x$-axis; $W$ and $L$ are the width and length of the medium, respectively; and $k_a$ is the scalar apparent conductivity that would be measured of the medium along the $x$-axis. During measurement the sides of the medium are insulated such that there is no flux at the boundaries perpendicular to the $x$-axis.
